# Java Reflections getSubTypeOf not returning all subclasses of the Hierarchy

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code:

```
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false));

        Set<Class<? extends Action>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Action.class);

        for (Class<?> subTypeOfActionInPackageNameClass : allClasses) {
           System.out.println(subTypeOfActionInPackageNameClass.getName());
        }
```

I would expect this to print all the class names of classes that extend Action but also all the classes that extends those classes as they indirectly extend Action too. For example C extends B extends A. If I do reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class); It only returns class B but I would have expected it to return class C as well.

I suspected this had something to do with the SubTypesScanner but looking into that I didn't find anything to get it to return class C as well.

Now the questions are:

a) Is it supposed to behave like that?
b) Provided the answer to a is yes, is there a way to return all the classes that directly and indirectly extend class A?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where did you get `Reflections` from?

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/blob/master/src/main/java/org/reflections/Reflections.java) I think

Comment: This is the import. **import org.reflections.Reflections;**  Do you want me to look for the specific library?

Comment: Yes Aaron, that would be the one.

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere, I've just tested it and it works as you expected : I've got classes A > B > C, `reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class)` does yield B and C. Are all of your classes in the same package? It looks like this tool only parses the packages you specify

Comment: Very strange. I am only looking at the package I defined in above code as packageName. It contains around 20 classes (that directly or indirectly extend Action) but it only returns 5 classes. Coincidently the classes that **directly** extend Action, but the others who extend it via other classes (C in the example) are not being returned. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps there are more Action classes and I am using the wrong one... will look further into this tomorrow.

Comment: I was using the right Action class. Still don't know why this issue occurs but obviously meanwhile I have found a work around :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) Yes it is supposed to behave like that if your classes are located in different packages. As stated in Reflections [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.11/org/reflections/Reflections.html) :

> Make sure to scan all the transitively relevant packages.  For
>   instance, given your class C extends B extends A, and both B and A are
>   located in another package than C, when only the package of C is
>   scanned - then querying for sub types of A returns nothing
>   (transitive), but querying for sub types of B returns C (direct). In
>   that case make sure to scan all relevant packages a priori.

b) There are multiple workarounds to solve your issue:

1. ***Put B and C in the same package***.
2. ***Use a package prefix common to B and C***. For example, if B is located in "my.package.b" and C is located in "my.package.c", then invoking `Set<Class<? extends Action>> allClasses = new Reflections("my.package").getSubTypesOf(A.class);` would return both B and C.
3. ***Scan explicitly all the transitively relevant packages***. For example, if B is in "my.package.b" and C is in "my.package.c", then invoking `Set<Class<? extends Action>> allClasses = new Reflections("my.package.b", "my.package.c").getSubTypesOf(A.class);` would return both B and C.